# Trigger OnTouchlistener in postDelayed method

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a TicTacToe game and currently, after someone wins, I have a postDelayed function that triggers after 5 milliseconds. During these 500 milliseconds, I can draw the winning character as well as display the winning animation. I was wondering if it was possible to make the user wait a mandatory 500 milliseconds and then tap to continue after the delay. Is this possible?

```
private void player1Wins() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            buttons[i][j].setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
    player1Points++;
    textViewPlayer1.setText(Integer.toString(player1Points));
    Toast.makeText(this, "Player 1 has won", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            resetBoard();
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(r, 500);
    winAnimation(winCondition);
}
```

Comment: 5 milisecond? do you mean 5 second?

Answer (score 0):

'Yeah you can do it. You can hide the button from xml in its properties like.'

```
android:visibility="gone";
```

'in your postDelayed Function after 5 miliseconds you can show this button to user like'

```
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               button.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);            
             }
        },500);
```

'and set it's click listener whatever you want'.

'Hope you get the solution.'